# If Node.js is single threaded, what is Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

If we say Node.js is single threaded and therefore there is just one thread that handles all the requests, what is Rails?

As I understand, Node.js is both the application and the server, but I am lost on what Rails would be? How does Rails handle requests in terms of threads/processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails can be single-threaded, it can be multi-threaded, it can be multi-process (where each process is single-threaded), or it can be multi-process where each process is multi-threaded.

It really all depends upon the app server you're using, and it kind of depends upon which Ruby implementation you're using.  MRI Ruby supports native threads as of 1.9, but it still maintains what's known as a global interpreter lock. The GIL prevents the Ruby interpreter from running in multiple threads at a time. In most cases that's not really a big deal though, because the thing threads are helping with the most is waiting for I/O.  If you're using either JRuby or Rubinius, they can actually run Ruby code in multiple threads at a time.

Check out the different app servers and what they offer in terms of concurrency features. Unicorn is a common one for deploying multi-process/single-threaded applications.  Puma is a newer app server that's capable of running multi-threaded applications, and I believe they're either adding (or maybe have added by now, I'm not sure) the ability to run multi-process as well.  Passenger seems to be able to work in every model I've listed above.

I hope this helps a little.  It should at least give you some things to Google for to find more information.